# Show integral is continuously differentiable with bounded derivative

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification

I have a question to [this notes](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Eryzhik/STANFORD/STANF272-17/book-split-chapt1and12.pdf), page 52.

It is written that

> > $$
> > \left\lvert\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(\frac{e^{-\lvert x-y\rvert^2/4(t-s)}}{(4\pi (t-s))^{n/2}}\right)g(s,y)\right\rvert\leq \frac{\lVert g\rVert_\infty}{\sqrt{t-s}}\frac{\lvert z\rvert e^{-\lvert z\rvert^2}}{(4\pi (t-s))^{n/2}},\quad z=\frac{x-y}{\sqrt{t-s}}
> > $$
> > As the volume element has the form $dz=\frac{dx}{(t-s)^{n/2}}$, this shows that the $x_i$-derivative of the integrand [of $J(t,x)$, see below] is dominated by an integrable function in $t$ and $z$.

I have two questions to this.

(1) The first is a minor thing: Shouldn't the right hand side be
$$
\frac{\lVert g\rVert_\infty}{\sqrt{t-s}}\frac{\lvert z\rvert e^{-\lvert z\rvert^2/4}}{(4\pi (t-s))^{n/2}}?
$$
Because when I substitute $x-y=z\sqrt{t-s}$, I get the additional $4$ in the exponent of the exponential.

(2) It is also said that one can use the estimate to conclude that $J(t,x)$ is $C^1$ in $x$ with bounded derivative. How can one deduce that?

Here $J(t,x)$ is defined on page 51, namely
$$
J(t,x)=\int_0^t\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{1}{(4\pi (t-s))^{n/2}}e^{-(x-y)^2/4 (t-s)} g(s,y)\, dy\, ds
$$

---

I think the boundedness of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}J(t,x)$ is a consequence of the dominated convergence theorem which tells us that, due to the domination of the derivative of the integrand by an integrable function, we have
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}J(t,x)=\int_{0}^t\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(\frac{e^{-\lvert x-y\rvert^2/4(t-s)}}{(4\pi (t-s))^{n/2}}\right)g(s,y)\, dy\, ds.\tag{*}
$$
Now I use this to estimate $\left\lvert\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}J(t,x)\right\rvert$ by substituting $z=\frac{y-x}{(t-s)^{n/2}}$  (I don't know why in the link they use $z=\frac{x-y}{(t-s)^{n/2}}$ because this produces a minus sign which is not helpful at all...):
$$
\begin{align*}
\left\lvert\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}J(t,x)\right\rvert&\leq\int_0^t\int_\mathbb{R}\left\lvert\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(\frac{e^{-\lvert x-y\rvert^2/4(t-s)}}{(4\pi (t-s))^{n/2}}\right)g(s,y)\right\rvert\, dy\, ds\\
&\leq \frac{\lVert g\rVert_\infty}{(4\pi)^{n/2}}\int_0^t\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{\lvert z\rvert e^{-\lvert z\rvert^2/4}}{\sqrt{t-s}}\, dz\, ds=\frac{8\sqrt{t}\lVert g\rVert_\infty}{(4\pi)^{n/2}}<\infty
\end{align*}
$$
Thus, the derivative is bounded. Does this make sense?

As to the continuity of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}J(t,x)$, this should be a *direct* consequence of the dominant convergence theorem and $(*)$, see for instance [Theorem 4.4.1](http://math.ncku.edu.tw/%7Erchen/2016%20Teaching/The%20dominated%20convergence%20theorem%20and%20applications.pdf). Applying this theorem to the integrand of $(*)$, we should get the continuity directly, shouldn't we?

Is there a more direct way to see the continuity? Would be nice.

Comment: For (1), I think you are right, according to page 53, (2.4.19).

Comment: Part (2) is more subtle, because the bound you obtain in (1) doesn't lend itself nicely to applying dominated convergence - the majorant also depends on $y, s$ implicitly via $z.$ While the conclusion should hold true, I don't immediately see how to argue this. Your argument of boundedness is correct, but you need to show $J$ is differentiable in the first place also.